# Electron `chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=...` won't shut down, eats up Memory

Tags: google-chrome, memory-usage, system-monitor, electron

I am trying to build an app with electron. When I do this, however, it appears that several chrome processes are created that don't shut down after closing electron. These processes eat up a lot of memory that slow down my computer. Most of the processes are called something like `chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=...`.

They occur even when I try to run the electron quick start app. I cannot figure out a way to stop these processes besides restarting the computer.

Here is a screenshot of these processes from my system monitor:

[image: Here is a screenshot of these processes from my system monitor]

This is what happens when I try to end the process. Some sort of weird non-functioning dialogue box pops up:

[image]

**Questions.**

1. Is this problem in fact created by electron?
2. Is there a way to shut these down within electron (e.g. via a flag)?
3. Is there a way to shut these processes down without restarting?
4. Would it just be better to submit an issue to the electron repo?

**Info.**

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Electron Version: v1.7.9
- Chrome Version: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It's Google chrome browser ["field trials"](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/05/field-trials-in-chrome-how-to-randomize-or-force-them/) AKA spy ware trojan. AFAIK you can't disable it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not caused by Electron.
I was searching for what they were doing consuming my memory when I ran across your question. But I am not using or even have Electron installed. I instead run Brave browser which is built upon chromium.
So this must be some chrome shit. I am new to this too.

Comment: It is not clear to me that brave does not use electron (though I have not looked into it closely). Check out the search for "electron" in their github [here](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Abrave+electron&unscoped_q=electron). However, this may well be a Chromium issue, since both certainly do use Chromium.

Comment: Also, @bign dhakal just a quick note about answers: usually your note would be added as a comment to the question, not as an answer, because it does not solve the issue but does potentially help out with a solution. Your reputation might be too low to comment, though, so maybe that's why you did it?

Comment: yeah, that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a couple of reasons for this.

You can try [disabling the 'background apps'](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28595501/Why-do-I-have-8-connections-using-Google-Chrome-when-it-was-not-opened-or-default-browser.html) - In Chrome Settings, click on the 'Advanced' button in the navigation menu on the left. Under 'System' uncheck

`Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed`

You can also try to clear the Cache. On Ubuntu-based systems, it is located in

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Application Cache
```

on [Windows](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/24386432?hl=en&msgid=24607307) it is usually under

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache`

As noted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1514112/304223), you can open the Chrome Task Manager to check which tabs consume the most CPU/Memory.